# Installing bzr-colo on Ubuntu Precise

Tags: ubuntu, installation, bazaar

I cannot for the life of me get bzr-colo to install.

First I've tried installing it to my user profile with:

```
bzr branch lp:bzr-colo ~/.bazaar/plugins/colo
```

I've also tried installing it system-wide with:

```
sudo pip install bzr-colo
```

Both the branching and `pip install` finished without errors, but I still get:

```
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "colo-fetch"
```

I'm open for all suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well erasing the `plugins` folder under my `~/.bazaar/` folder and reinstalling all plugins did it.

Initially I've tried deleting `~/.bazaar/plugins/colo` and branching **bzr-colo** but it didn't work. Either branching the repo didn't really work, or I really needed to delete all plugins. Be it any way, it works now.